# React Native Expo - Location service

Tags: react-native, google-play, expo, location-services

Im trying to submit an app to google play console but it is showing an error ->

This release includes permissions that haven't been declared in Play Console. Go to Sensitive app permissions to update your permission declarations.

But Im not asking the user for any location permission or have any code to do the same.

The closest thing that Im getting from the user is their timezone using expo-localization

Is there a way to fix is ?

Comment: Have you found any solution...? I am faced with the same problem. It's blocking me from releasing an App.

Comment: yes, In your app.json under android add `"permissions": []` and inside the square brackets add permissions according to this list [link](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v40.0.0/sdk/permissions/)